How to make a large PNG sprite
Can anyone please recommend some software which can handle large PNG sprites?
I have a task to do for a developer. And he needs me to double the output resolution of the PNG graphics sequence.
I have a file which is 2000px X 800px, and I have a controller which is 400pixels.
When I double the resolution the controller becomes 800 pixels, When I animate it,
150 frames x 800 pixels, the file dimensions will be 120,000 vertical pixel sprite.
I usually would use the website: codetheweb for PNG sprites, but this one is a very different requirement, codetheweb giving me an error when I try to save the file.
I also would use another software found on Github called: GlueIt. A free open source PNG sprite maker. But this is also limited to size output.
What is the best method to achieve this task, but Im a graphic designer, not a developer/programmer. So would this type of task be handed over for a developer to find a solution?
Thanks for your time.


Welcome to CG Stack Exchange! Here are a few suggestions to improve the clarity of your question:

Clearly describe the expected input and output.
Explain why your current method isn't working—Is it due to the size being too large?
Instead of asking for specific software, focus on solutions. Coding suggestions might be more helpful and less likely to be considered off-topic (e.g., as off-site software recommendations).
Consider editing your post for better clarity.


I've edited my questions, thank you for the recommendation on how to structure my inquiry.
